# Error uploading a file to a ftp server

Tags: python, ftp

I have a program which sends a text file to a ftp server. The code is:

```
def sendBug():

    session = ftplib.FTP('ftp://xxxx.xxxx.xxxx.xxxx', " ", " ")
    bugfile = open(bugreport.txt, "r")
    session.storlines("STOR bugreport.txt", bugfile)
    bugfile.close()
    session.quit()
```

However, when I run that script, I'm getting something like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1470, in __call__
return self.func(*args)
 File "C:\Users\Nitro\Desktop\py2exe stuff\school firewall ui.py", line 46, in getnews
ftp= ftplib.FTP(server)
File "C:\Python27\lib\ftplib.py", line 120, in __init__
self.connect(host)
File "C:\Python27\lib\ftplib.py", line 135, in connect
self.sock = socket.create_connection((self.host, self.port), self.timeout)
File "C:\Python27\lib\socket.py", line 553, in create_connection
for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM):
gaierror: [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed
```

any way to fix this? Im hosting a ftp server with IIS. And school firewall ui is my program.

Comment: What is `xxxx.xxxx.xxxx.xxxx`?, also please add the entire trace-back so it will be easier to understand which line caused the error.

Comment: @ Kobi K it is my ftp server ip address, and I edited the post.

Comment: Your username and password are " " (space)?

Comment: @ Kobi K no authentication is required to access the files.

Comment: Try removing the protocol from the IP (ie just try `'123.123.123.123'`). If there is no username or password required you should not pass them in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for  first Server line doen't need the `"ftp://"`

Basiclly `gaierror: [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed` means that the ftp module can't understand the `'ftp://xxxx.xxxx.xxxx.xxxx'` address you gave him - host name.

`gaierror` from Docs:

This exception is raised for address-related errors, for getaddrinfo() and getnameinfo(). The accompanying value is a pair (error, string) representing an error returned by a library call. string represents the description of error, as returned by the gai_strerror() C function. The error value will match one of the EAI_* constants defined in this module.

You are passing `ftplib.FTP()` with host, username and password (both user and password are space at your case)

if it's supposed to be anonymous just use:

```
ftp = ftplib.FTP('you address')     
ftp.login()
```

If it still doesn't work try to ping your address or try to connect some known FTP to understated where is the problem.

You can also try this [link](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/code-snippets-source-code/how-to-use-ftp-in-python/) it's very useful

For more info about python FTP try the [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ftplib.html)