# Fetching data from a ftp server

Tags: python, ftp, ftplib

I have some code like this:

```
def getnews():
try:
    server = 'ftp://25.102.81.171'
    ftp= ftplib.FTP(server)
    username = ' '
    password = ' '
    ftp.login(username,password)
    filename = 'news_2014.txt'
    path = 'news'
    ftp.cwd(path)
    textlines = []
    ftp.retrlines('RETR' + filename, textlines.append)
    newswindw = Toplevel(background="grey")
    news1 = Label(newswindw, text="textlines", background="white")
    news1.pack()
except IOError:
    tkMessageBox.showerror("failed", "failed for some reason.")
```

every time I run it, I get the exception, and if I run it without the try, it gives me a gaeierror: getadderinfo failed
any way to fix this?

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/20970944/1982962

Comment: there is no need to ask the same question twice.

Answer (score 0):

the server line doesn't need "ftp://"

Comment: It answers why it wasn't working.  I knew why it wasn't working and I stated so in my answer.  I was trying some other approach besides saying "You're wrong".  My answer was the softest shortest way I could say how to fix it.

Comment: Retracted.. But you should maybe be less short and soft.